# How to select the OpenRC init system during Linux installation?

Tags: linux, systemd, init

I want to install Debian Linux (on a 2009 Macbook Pro), opting for the OpenRC init system. By default, Debian uses Systemd. During the installation, I did not see any option to choose the init system; how can I choose OpenRC (or Sysvinit)?

Once Systemd is installed, can I replace it with OpenRC, or is it not feasible due to how invasive Systemd is?

How can I opt for OpenRC during installation?

Is it possible to have more than one init system, and choose which one to use through, e.g., a configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenRC is not well ported to Debian, they are not thinking on OpenRC as a full replacement of both SystemD and SysVinit, the current version available for Debian Stretch it's 0.23 and this version doesn't have openrc-init (replacement for init), even if you migrate to sid or testing you have version 0.34 and this version includes openrc-init and indeed OpenRC can work as a full init but this package doesn't include the scripts for agetty, or the symlinks for shutdown, reboot, etc. and this means some work and for sure some problems.

My point on one who wants to run a distro with full OpenRC it's to install Gentoo or some of their derivatives, and also some Arch based distros like Parabola (OpenRC version), Hyperbola or Artix.

Comment: What is, in your opinion, the best init system for Debian?

Comment: I have only a few objections on Debian, one of them is the lack on init freedom, if you want to remove SystemD you have to make a FrankeDebian. So the response is clear, whatever you have or not against SystemD, it's the best init for Debian because it's the only one 100% supported.

Comment: A good reason not to use Debian, then. Probably in my case the best option is [Devuan](https://devuan.org/os/init-freedom/).

Comment: Maybe you can try Slackware, Arch, or Gentoo, these distros are a great point for learning, Slackware works on SysVinit, Arch have many forks to work with OpenRC, and Gentoo's default init it's OpenRC. I don't want to use the word difficult for these distros, it's something different but i think that every GNU/Linux user have to try these distros.

Answer (score 0):

I found some answers in this forum:
 http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=134915

#### Summary:

- Systemd and OpenRC can coexist.
- OpenRC can be downloaded and installed from a computer with Systemd.

Still wondering if Systemd, even if not active, still messes the system up...